# WTForms- SelectField choice (sub-category) autofills StringField (main category) using table data

Tags: postgresql, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a table with the following data:

```
 programme_sub_category | main_programme_category 
------------------------+--------------------
 EVENT                  | ROT
 LIVE MUSIC             | LIVE MUSIC
 CONCERT                | LIVE MUSIC
 OPERA                  | LIVE MUSIC
 REHEARSAL              | UNPUBLISHED
 DRAMA                  | PRE-REC
 IDENT                  | UNPUBLISHED
 UNPUBLISHED            | UNPUBLISHED
```

The data in column 1 is used to populate a  drop-down menu where the user can select the programme_sub_category. On the same page, I also have a StringField for the main_programme_category. Is it possible for me to auto update the StringField of the main_programme_category field on the webpage in real time, so that even before the form is submitted, the field auto-updates based on the selection of the programme_sub_category? Does Flask-WTForms allow for this kind of functionality?

Comment: You could do it using JavaScript. Since it's on the webpage, is there a reason you want to go back to the server and use WTForms for this?

Comment: No not really, i'm just not very experienced with web development and didn't know it could be done in Javascript. Is it fairly straight forward?

Comment: Yeah, especially using jquery - if you can include that.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is client side, you can do this easily using JavaScript:

The easiest way would be with jQuery. See their **Examples** section at: https://api.jquery.com/change/

They are using a `div` instead of an `input` field, but the idea is the same. In your case, since it's a standard dropdown, the example can be modified:

```
...
<select name="programme_sub_category">
  <option val="ROT">EVENT</option>
  <option val="LIVE MUSIC">LIVE MUSIC</option>
  <option val="LIVE MUSIC">CONCERT</option>
  <option val="LIVE MUSIC">OPERA</option>
  <option val="UNPUBLISHED">REHEARSAL</option>
  ...
</select>
<input name="main_programme_category" type="text" />

<script>
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    var str = $( "select option:selected" ).val();
    $( "input" ).val( str );
});
</script>
...
```

==========

If your dropdown doesn't show up, like the example, on your page, you'd have to probably post an example of what the HTML looks like.